# How to boot always from HD

Tags: windows-xp, boot

When I start my computer I always have to set the boot from HD. How can I save this option? 
(I have a windows xp)
Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into your BIOS and change it there. It will be under the "Boot" menu.

To get into your BIOS you need to press **F2**, **F8**, or **Delete** as your PC first starts to boot up (exactly which one depends on your individual PC, so trial and error is your best bet).